# How to send the client id and secret id of OAuth2 using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the Rest API for OAuth2 developed using spring boot with resource server and authorization server. I could successfully fetch the token using cURL, POSTMAN Rest client and could request the granted service using the token provided by OAuth. Now, i need to know how to pass the OAuth2 client_id, secret_id using angular2.
i am passing request as
 getOAuthToken(clientCredintial):Observable {

```
var body = `username=admin&password=nex1234`;
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let response = this.http.post(`${AppSettings.BACK_ENDPOINT}/oauth/token`,body,{ headers: headers });
let oauthTokenItems = response.map(mapOAuthTokenItems);
return oauthTokenItems;
```

}
    but i am getting Exceptions on Browser as 
    OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/rwsweb/oauth/token 401 ()

```
oauth-token:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load                 http://localhost:8080/rwcweb/oauth/token. Response for preflight has invalid     HTTP status code 401
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
```

Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

Use the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private urlLogin: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.urlLogin = "http://yourserver/oauth/token";
    }

    public login(user) {

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("yourclientid" + ':' + "yourclientsecret")
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        let data = "username=" + user.yourlogin + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(user.yourpass) + "&grant_type=password&" +
            "client_secret=yourclientsecret&client_id=yourclientid";

        return this.http.post(this.urlLogin, data, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried above but now i am getting one exception on Chrome brawser as XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/rwcweb/oauth/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: Yes, I tested in Postman.  in that works properly. and this exception "preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401" is not comes on Safari Browser, but in Chrome. because if we passing the request as POST with all credential then Chrome converting that into OPTIONS method. i am not  understanding how can i pass this request on Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved using pure [javascript in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201731/django-oauth2-unsupported-grant-type). For angular 5, I was able to get a 200 response status using this code:

```
getAccessToken(username: string, password: string): Observable<AuthToken> {

   let oauth2_token_endpoint = '<your_token_endpoint>';
   let oauth2_client_id = '<your_client_id>';
   let oauth2_client_secret = '<your_client_secret>';

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(oauth2_client_id + ':' + oauth2_client_secret)
        })
    };


    const body = 'client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=password&username={2}&password={3}'
        .replace('{0}', oauth2_client_id)
        .replace('{1}', oauth2_client_secret)
        .replace('{2}', username)
        .replace('{3}', password);

    // console.log(body);

    return this.http.post<AuthToken>(oauth2_token_endpoint, body, httpOptions);
}
```

AuthToken Interface :

```
export interface AuthToken {
    access_token: string,
    token_type: string,
    expires_in: number,
    refresh_token: string,
    scope: Array<string>
}
```

Your Login function would look like this:

```
login(username: any, password: any): void {

    this.getAccessToken(username, password).subscribe(
        response => {
            // ...any login logic- cookies and all the good stuff goes here
            this.isLoggedIn = true; 
            console.log(response);
        },
        error => {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```