# Django OAuth2 unsupported_grant_type

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to send a request with django to get an access_token from my api using OAuth2. I'm executing this code :

```
data = {'username': 'admin', 'password': '123123', 'grant_type': 
'password','client_id': 'xxx','client_secret': 'xxx'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

When I send this request I get this error :

> {'error': 'unsupported_grant_type'}

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone is interested the correct request was :

```
    payload = "grant_type=password&client_secret=xxx&client_id=xxx&username=username&password=password"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was using application/json as content-type. Switching to x-www-form-urlencoded was all I needed to change to get it working for client_credentials grant type.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to encode data in url, you can put this in your settings.

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {                                                                                                                                                                      
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore',                                                                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and later I found that the grant type should be a string.

```
payload = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': refresh_token}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you explain the answer. Welcome to the community.

Comment: The grant type should be entered as a string value. (Within single quotes).  Thank you very much for the feedback.