# OAuth storing client id and secret in database

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I was reading an [article](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50) about `OAuth 2.0` with `jwt` tokens. Interesting part is when author describes `client_secret`, he says:

> In a non-trivial implementation client ids and passwords will be securely stored in a database and retrievable through a separate API that clients applications access during deployment.

Now let's say I have a frontend app in angular and a backend app in spring with MySQL db.

My question is what author meant by the aforementioned quote. Is it, that
 client (frontend app in this case) makes a call using `client_id`
    and `secret` (nothing changes here), but backend is checking
    provided "credentials" not by comparing with values stored in plain-text (in
    `application.properties` in that case), but making a hash from received values and
    comparing with hashed version in db ?

---

**EDITED**:
[image: Example of use case]

1. User `john doe` opens `log in` page. Provides credentials: `username:john.doe` and `password:john1`. Clicks `sign in`.
2. Angular-frontend intercepts request, and executes a method (f.e. `obtainTokenForUser()`) in order to get a short-period-valid jwt token for the user. For that reason angular-app sends an `OAuth2.0`-compliant request to the `authorization server`. Before sending contant `AWS KMS` to get its `client_id` and `secret` in order to attach to the request. In the end, the request from angular to auth server looks like: `curl front-app-sp3:frnt4pP@<auth_server_ip_addr>:<auth_server_port>/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=john.doe -d password=john1`
3. `Authorization server` contacts `AWS KMS` for received `client_id:front-app-sp3` and `client_secret:frnt4pP`. It finds the entry, passwords matches, validation correct. `Auth server` generates a JWT token valid f.e. `5 minutes`. The token is signed by the server using `AS_pr1v4t3` private key. `Authorization server` returns a token to angular app.
4. User is logged in. User requests a resource in the main app (in spring), thus angular adds an obtained token and sends the request to the "Main-web application".
5. `Resource server` in the "Main-web application" validates token. Token is correct and valid. Resource is returned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's what the author is referring to. He is talking about instead of having `client_id` and `client_secret` in your application.properties they are to be stored in a DB which your backend can access through a different API. I would argue that the `client_id` belongs more to the application.properties than the secret management service though. **Your front-end (angular app in this case) should never have access to client-id or the secret. Your server which the angular app is connected to (through some REST services I imagine) should never have direct access to the secrets either, it should go through a separate secret management API.** It's ok for your server to have the `client_id` in the application properties, but the secret should be stored in a very secure place.

This is an already implemented pattern though. Instead of having the secret values directly in the app.config / application.properties file you should have them in something like:

- [AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/)
- [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/)

These would allow you to store / update / retrieve and rotate your secrets.

Comment: to be sure I got it: 1) Author of the article (Mr. Nouhoun) is talking about accessing `client_id` and `secret` by the back-end side, while you're taking about accessing them by the front-end side 2) Mr. Nouhoun says: you can keep `client_id` and `secret` either in `app.properites` (directly accessible by the back-end) or in a database - accessible by a separate API. 3) you say: when it comes to accessing these information by front-end, it should be via a "key managment service". Did I get it right  ?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect a bit better

Comment: 1. If you're talking about front-end as in your angular app that's a no. You should only have the token in there, not the client_id or the client_secret. If you're talking about the front end as in the server side which directly communicates with the angular app (so your REST endpoints etc..) then yes I was referring to that. 2. Correct - he says that. 3. you should never access that information through your front-end.

Comment: I have created a little picture and with an example/simple use case. I would be more than happy if you could take a look at it and give me some feedback.

Comment: @user3529850 Your "Main web-application" should make the call to retrieve the client_id and client_secret - not your angular app. Your angular app cannot be aware of what the client secret is at any stage, that's a significant security problem.

Comment: 1) Everyone use that in angular: https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-oauth2-angular (`OAUTH2 Login In Angular`) and https://www.baeldung.com/angular-4-upgrade-for-spring-security-oauth/ (`obtainAccessToken()`) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808929/how-to-send-the-client-id-and-secret-id-of-oauth2-using-angular-2?rq=1 So why do you consider it major security risk ?
2) If I changed "Main web-application" to make the call to retrieve the `client_id` and `client_secret`, would remain elements on my schema be ok and secure enough to implement ?

Comment: How can the "Main web-application" retrieve the clientId clientSecret? I guess that to access AWS Key Management Service another token is needed. How would it work to retrieve that? If again a client credential flow is used, I would need to store the AWS Key Management Service secrets somewhere.